require('crypto'); module-not-found error in Nextjs Authjs
Error message
> dev

next dev --turbo --port 3001

✘ Console Ninja DOES NOT SUPPORT next.js when run with --turbo, see "someurlthatsodontallow"
▲ Next.js 14.2.1 (turbo)

Local:        http://localhost:3001
Environments: .env

✓ Starting...
/bin/sh: 1: pnpm: not found
⨯ ./node_modules/pg/lib/crypto/utils-webcrypto.js:1:20
Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto'

1 | const nodeCrypto = require('crypto')
|                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2 |
3 | module.exports = {
4 |   postgresMd5PasswordHash,

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
⨯ ./node_modules/pg/lib/crypto/utils-legacy.js:5:20
Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto'
3 | // which does not support the WebCrypto.subtle API.
4 |

5 | const nodeCrypto = require('crypto')
|                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
6 |
7 | function md5(string) {
8 |   return nodeCrypto.createHash('md5').update(string, 'utf-8').digest('hex')

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
⨯ ./node_modules/pg/lib/crypto/utils-webcrypto.js:1:20
Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto'

1 | const nodeCrypto = require('crypto')
|                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2 |
3 | module.exports = {
4 |   postgresMd5PasswordHash,

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
⨯ ./node_modules/pg/lib/crypto/utils-legacy.js:5:20
Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto'
3 | // which does not support the WebCrypto.subtle API.
4 |

5 | const nodeCrypto = require('crypto')
|                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
6 |
7 | function md5(string) {
8 |   return nodeCrypto.createHash('md5').update(string, 'utf-8').digest('hex')

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
✓ Compiled in 606ms
✓ Ready in 2.6s
[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { handlers } from '@/lib/auth';
export const { GET, POST } = handlers;

auth.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Google from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import { Pool } from 'pg';

const pool = new Pool({
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  max: 20,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000
});

export const authOptions = {
  adapter: PostgresAdapter(pool),
  providers: [Google]
};
export const { auth, handlers, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(authOptions);

middleware.ts
import { auth } from '@/lib/auth';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)']
};

export default auth((req) => {
  if (!req.auth) {
    const url = '/login'; // Redirect URL
    return NextResponse.redirect(url); // Redirect the user to the login page
  }
});

export function middleware(request: {
  headers: HeadersInit | undefined;
  url: string;
}) {
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  requestHeaders.set('x-url', request.url);

  return NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders
    }
  });
}

package.json
...

  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/pg-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "@neondatabase/serverless": "^0.9.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/node": "20.12.7",
    "@types/react": "18.2.78",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.25",
    "@vercel/analytics": "^1.2.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.20.14",
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.30.8",
    "lucide-react": "^0.368.0",
    "next": "14.2.1",
    "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.18",
    "pg": "^8.11.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "server-only": "^0.0.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "typescript": "5.4.5"
  },

...




I tried to go with docs line by line.
i am trying to create nextjs app with nextauth and PGSQL.
when i run npm run dev i want to get a simple app with running backend and database connection.
